# Null Pointer Exception with HashMap and Collections

Tags: collections, android-listview, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I'm trying to sort my ListView alphabetically and I'm pretty stuck. This is the only method I've found that gives no direct errors, but it throws a Null Pointer Exception when run on the emulator. If anyone has a better way of doing it I'm open to offers!

Here's the section of my activity that causes the problems: (I don't want to post the whole activity, it's pretty large and wouldn't be much help. There's nothing else relating to this bit of code in my activity, apart from

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipeList;
```

and

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked,
                int position, long id) {

                String stringName = (String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));

        Intent intenttwo = new Intent(SecondScreenActivity.this, ThirdScreenActivity.class);
        intenttwo.putExtra("position", stringName);
        startActivity(intenttwo);

//EDIT:  I added an extra bit here to show that position is a string (name
         of item) rather than an int.
```

that define recipeList and position)

```
Collections.sort(recipeList,new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>(){
    public int compare(HashMap<String,String> mapping1,HashMap<String,String> mapping2){
        return mapping1.get("position").compareTo(mapping2.get("position"));
    };

});
```

and here's the logcat:

```
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.SecondScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1890)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.example.myapp.SecondScreenActivity.onCreate(SecondScreenActivity.java:91)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-30 10:46:02.945: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

also, I don't have anywhere near 2180 lines, so I'm not sure where that's coming from.
Thanks very much to anyone who can help

Comment: Can you post the rest of the rest of the stacktrace? It looks like something you handed in to Android is silently not being flagged until it makes it into Android code.

Comment: is there anything else there that helps finding the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Android development, but it looks like you are using "position" as a key.  Are you wanting to use the int variable position as a key to your map? So shouldn't you be using:

mapping1.get(position+"").compareTo(mapping2.get(position+""));

or

mapping1.get(Integer.toString(position)).compareTo(mapping2.get(Integer.toString(position)));

Comment: Hmm, when I try the first one it says 'position cannot be resolved to a variable', as it needs to be in "s to be recognised. The second one either gives me the same error when position is not in "s, and when I put "s around it the error moves to 'Integer.toString' and says 'The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String). I'm no java expert, but that looks like it's recognising "position" as a string? Anyway, thanks very much for the help and hopefully this'll help!